# Pointer incrementation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

```
int* dividers_of(int x, int ammount){
int i,j = 1;
int* dividers = (int*)calloc(ammount,sizeof(int)); /* calloc initializes int array to 0!*/

for(i=0;i<ammount;i++){

    while( (x%j) != 0){
        j++;
    }

*(dividers+i) = j;

/*DOESNT WORK ( int* dividers stays on 0-0-0)
*dividers = j;
dividers++; */ 

j++;
}
return dividers;
}
```

I'm trying to find out what's wrong with the code that doesn't work, I'm assigning `int j` to `*dividers` and then making `dividers` point to the next `int` in its array. The result should be a pointer to an array which contains the `int` dividers of an `int x`.

Unfortunately the result if i do it like this is the following array:

```
dividers[] = {0,0,0};
```

which means nothing has changed since `calloc` fills the array like this.

Whats happening at

```
*dividers = j;
dividers++;
```

?

Comment: It's spelled `amount`, not `ammount`.

Comment: Don't [cast the result of `calloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: 1/ **We can't reproduce the issue.** This is a common issue for newcomers, so please read the FAQ within the help center of this website to learn how to write questions in such a way that you allow others to reproduce (and thus experiment with) the issue. I'm done linking directly to the section. If we're going to talk about courtesy, you should have read that entire section before you posted here. It's kind of rude to ignore the community standards like this.

Comment: Could you please add some examples of the expected outcome of your function?

Comment: 2/ Along-side your MCVE (you'll read about those when you read the entirety of our *help center* to discover what questions are appropriate here), I highly recommend linking with debug symbols (i.e. `gcc -g ...`) and attaching `valgrind` output to your question, because it seems like it'll be *one of those* questions...

Comment: `*(dividers+i)` is the same as `dividers[i]`. No need to increment pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you increment `dividers` in the loop:

```
    dividers++;
```

then it won't have its original value at the end:

```
return dividers;
```

With the increment, your function returns a pointer past the end of the array, not a pointer to the beginning of the array.

The easiest way to fix this is to save the original pointer in another variable at the start:

```
int *dividers = ...;
int *dividers_start = dividers;

/* ... modify dividers here ... */

return dividers_start;
```

But you could also use pointer arithmetic to undo the increment:

```
return dividers - ammount;
```

Comment: What happens to the value of the array?

Comment: @ADITYA What array?